# JBPM 6 web application set up

Tags: drools, jbpm, wildfly-8, drools-guvnor

I am going to develop an web application in JBPM 6.1 using wildfly 8.1 final. But when I deploy my web application in jboss server , it gives following error.

15:49:29,967 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Jbpm6WithMaven.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Jbpm6WithMaven.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Inject org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.DefaultBeanLocator.autoPublish(Injector)
  at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.DefaultBeanLocator.autoPublish(DefaultBeanLocator.java:0)

I was working on this problem for days and hours.Please can anyone help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to check the dependencies that you are adding to your webapp, there is something wrong in there and it doesn't seems to be related with jbpm. You need to solve this issue WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Inject org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.DefaultBeanLocator.autoPublish